# Multinomial logistic regression and marginal effects

Tags: r, regression, logit

I am trying to calculate the marginal effects of a multinomial logistic regression. To do this I use the `mlogit` package and the `effects()` function.

Here is how the procedure works (source : `effects()` function of `mlogit` package) :

```
data("Fishing", package = "mlogit")
Fish <- mlogit.data(Fishing, varying = c(2:9), shape = "wide", choice = "mode")
m <- mlogit(mode ~ price | income | catch, data = Fish)
# compute a data.frame containing the mean value of the covariates in the sample
z <- with(Fish, data.frame(price = tapply(price, index(m)$alt, mean), 
 catch = tapply(catch, index(m)$alt, mean), 
income = mean(income)))
# compute the marginal effects (the second one is an elasticity
effects(m, covariate = "income", data = z)
effects(m, covariate = "price", type = "rr", data = z)
effects(m, covariate = "catch", type = "ar", data = z)
```

I have no problem with first step (`mlogit.data()` function). I think my problem is in the specification of the multinomial regression.

My regression (for example with three variables) is on the form: `Y ~ 0 | X1 + X2 + X3`. When I try to estimate the marginal effects for a model with 2 variables, there is no problem, however for 3 variables R console returns me the following error: "Error in if (rhs% in% c (1, 3)) {: argument is of length zero " (translation from error in R console in french).

To understand what is my problem I tried to perform a multinomial regression of similar shape on the dataset "Fishing", i.e.,: `mode ~ 0 | income + price + catch` (even if this form has no "economic" sense.) Again the R console returns me the same error for 3 variables but manages to estimate these effects for a model with two variables.

This leads me to think that my problem really comes from the specification of my multinomial regression.  Do you know how I could find a solution to my problem? Or could you suggest another logit multinomial regression form?

Comment: Have you gotten an answer?  I am having a very similar issue and need help.

Comment: I just noticed you posted same question on TalkStats web site and someone gave you the hint to change the source code.  I do not know how to do that.  'the source code of effects.mlogit. In line 16 you should replace "cov.list <- lapply(attr(formula(object), "rhs"), as.character)" with "cov.list <- strsplit(as.character(attr(formula(object), "rhs")), " + ", fixed = TRUE)". '

Answer (score 2):

The | is used to separate individual variant and alternative variant regressors. In this example, price and catch rate vary through alternatives (fishing from a pier, beach,..) and income does not change depending on alternatives.

So, I'm inclined to advise you to write your mlogit regression like so:

```
 m<-mlogit(mode ~ price + catch| income , data = Fish, reflevel="beach")
```

Then you can call:

```
 effects(m,covariate="{insert whichever you want}",type="{whichever you select}")
```

I tried it on a subset of this data and it worked.

Comment: welcome to [stats.se]!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].